# How to store sensitive data in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

So I'm new to the whole cloud computing infrastructure and I'm trying to grasp the best practices and today it came to my mind. How do I store sensitive data in AWS what services do I need to utilize and what architecture shall I build for it, I wrote a scenario down to further explain my question.

Let's say I have a user registration and I need from every user to input a secret key that I need to access some kind of 3rd party service on their behalf (let's assume that it's the only to access that service and no other way to access it) how do I store it in my database let's say RDS for example without compromising other IAM users from accessing the database but all they say is an encrypted secret key not the plain text.

I searched online and found some saying KMS and some saying Secrets Manager some saying Backend Encrypting and some says Frontend Encrypting which way shall I go with?

Whoever decides to answer this question thanks in advance but please elaborate as much as you can because I'm still trying the get the concepts and trying to leverage the "Cloud" capabilities as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Two common approaches would be to encrypt the secret key at either a) the application level, or b) the database level.  To encrypt the key inside your application, you would use some reliable encryption method, such as SHA-256 or SHA-512.  The key would be encrypted and non accessible even before you write it out to your database as binary content.  To encrypt at the database level, there are a number of options, depending on your particular database.  If your RDBMS support encrypted columns, then, from your application, you may simply write out the secret key to its column.  The database would then automatically handle encrypting on the way in, and also decrypting the secret key on the way out, when you go to read it.